# how to insert headers on MultipartRequest in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

below is the code that I tried but it didn't work, how to insert header on MultipartRequest?

```
      var id = prefs.getInt('id');
      var token = prefs.getString('accessToken');
      var uri = Uri.parse('https://url.com/submit/$id');
      var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
      };

      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
      request.files.add(
        await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', _files.first.path.toString()),
      );
      var response = await request.send();
```

Comment: I believe this answer can help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52008741/2352776)

Comment: can you help with my custom code?

Answer (score 0):

Headers is a map attribute of the request object, you can simply use map methods on it:

```
request.headers.addAll(headers)
```